# Could you help me with this When clause?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

> 2. The Agency shall, in collaboration with the Member States and the Commission, draw up the functional specifications for the Eudra vigilance database, together with a timeframe for their implementation. The Agency shall prepare an annual report on the Eudravigilance database and send it to the European Parliament, the Council and the Commission. The first annual report shall be prepared by 2 January 2013.
>      The Management Board of the Agency shall on the basis of an independent audit report that takes into account the recommendation of the Pharmacovigilance Risk Assessment Committee **confirm and announce when the Eudravigilance database has achieved full functionality and the system meets the functional specifications drawn up pursuant to the first subparagraph.** [EU Regulation](https://ec.europa.eu/health/sites/health/files/files/eudralex/vol-1/reg_2004_726/reg_2004_726_en.pdf)

Could you please help me with the last sentence?

*...confirm and announce when ...*

Does it mean the management board of the agency shall **confirm and announce the time when** the database has achieved full funtionality and the system meets the functional specifications? (= the board shall confirm and announce the time when the database is completed.) (so the When clause is a noun)

Or does it mean **When the Eudravigilance database has achieved full functionality and the system meets the functional specifications drawn up pursuant to the first subparagraph, the board shall confirm and announce it**? (so the When clause is an adverb.)

If it's the second meaning, wouldn't "confirm and announce" need an object?

Comment: A time/condition clause is often used as the object of a word like *confirm, say, report*: e.g. "Say when you have enough."

Answer (score 1):

> The Management Board of the Agency shall ... confirm and announce when the Eudravigilance database has achieved full functionality and the system meets the functional specifications drawn up pursuant to the first subparagraph.

This is what I understand from the text.

The Management Board of the Agency will confirm and announce two things after two conditions are met.

The conditions that need to be met are the following:

1. the database needs to achieve full functionality
2. the system needs to meet the functional specifications

When these conditions are satisfied/met/achieved, the Management Board of the Agency will make an announcement confirming that the two key conditions are met and that the database is now ready to be used by the appropriate authorities.

Comment: Thanks. I guess when clause is an adverb clause in this usage. Then wouldn't "confirm and acnnounce" need an object?

Comment: @MangoGummy I certainly feel that an object would make it easier to parse. But one is not necessary. These options for example would be much easier to understand: *"...the board shall confirm and announce **it** [as you already say this]", "... confirm **the public/interested parties** when ...", "...the board shall confirm and announce **that the database is ready for research purposes** when ..."* But the way they wrote it does not surprise me. The language used in government legislation is often very convoluted.